# Drupal Content Types

Tags: nodes

Content types that are created recently are not showing up. They are displayed in content type list but not in "Add content" list and navigation menu. I tried few solutions like:

1. I checked in the database node_type table if the fields type and orig_type are same; they are same.
2. I configured the navigation block to access all content types, though it is not necessary.
3. I tried to do add the link directly in navigation menu, but the link is not getting added to the menu.
4. I cleared the cache several times and run the cron tasks too.
5. Its is not even permissions, I have given them already.
   Can anyone help? I am stuck and I cannot start everything from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a permission issue.

Comment: You'll need to expand on this quite a bit.  Which permissions could be affecting it?  How does op go about changing permissions?

Comment: Swathi.m posted this comment as an edit: "Not actually, because I have given all the permissions. And i seriously am stuck. I cannot start everything from scratch as there are many things done. Sorry I edited your comment as my comment is not getting posted!"

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new content type, it should be visible in the "Content Type" page.

If they are not visible, then it could be a permission issue: You have to give permission for creating/modifying nodes using content types you added. The only exceptions are the first user created for a Drupal site (who always has all the permissions) and the users with the "administer content types" permission.

Comment: I would also suggest checking permissions. By default a new content type will not allow anyone to create.

Comment: @rooby will not allow anyone but admin ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in through admin and you are not getting the list of content type in "Add content" list and navigation menu, but displayed in "Content type" list page, then it mean that links are deleted from "Navigation" menu.

I know that this is not best solution for the problem, but you can add menu item in the "Navigation" menus for the content type. You can add link url for menu item as "node/add/[machine_name_of_content_type]" and title same as name of content type.